# How will I compare a text input if it is empty or not?

Tags: jquery

How will I compare a text input if it is empty or not inside a Jquery statement? Is the code below alright?

```
$(#'generate').click(function(){
   if(parseInt($('#lastname').val,10)==0){
      alert("Should Not Be Empty!");
   }
}
```

Comment: No but `$('#lastname').val() == ""` would do the trick - youre not calling 'val', its a function

Answer (score 1):

do you mean:

```
if($.trim( $('#lastname').val() ) != ""){
    alert("Should Not Be Empty!");
}
```

OR

```
if($.trim( $('#lastname').val() ).length  > 0){
    alert("Should Not Be Empty!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(#'generate')` should be `$('#generate')` and `$('#lastname').val` should `$('#lastname').val()`, because `val()` is a method.

```
$('#generate').click(function(){
   if( !$.trim( $('#lastname').val() ) ){
      alert('Should Not Be Empty!');
   }
}
```

But you tried `parseInt($('#lastname').val(),10)` which will output `NaN` if, input box is empty, not give `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
$('#generate').click(function(){
    if($('#lastname').val().trim() != "") {
       alert("Should Not Be Empty!");
    }
}
```

Also, there is a typo

```
  $(#'generate').click(function(){
//   ^   Right here
```

Comment: I just mistyped #'generate and #lastname.val......my problem is now solved.